# Check Every 8 Numbers in ES6/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need to check if index is 8,9,  16,17,  24,25 ...
How will I check it?

Pls check my code below:

```
{
  person &&
    person.map((data, index) => (
      <div
        className={`${
          (index === index % 8) === 0
            ? "correct"
            : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div>{data.name}</div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```

Comment: Instead of `(index === index % 8) === 0` You can use `( (index % 8 === 0) ||  ( (index - 1) % 8 === 0 ) )`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: If value of index is like 8,9, 16,17, 24, 25.  In short multiples of 8 and 8 plus 1 and should start from 8 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
{
  person &&
    person.map((data, index) => (
      <div
        className={`${
          (index > 1 && (index % 8 == 1 || index % 8 == 0))
            ? "correct"
            : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div>{data.name}</div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```

Or to make this look a bit pretty! Just make a function to check this condition for you!

```
const isCorrectCondition = i => (i > 1 && (i % 8 == 1 || i % 8 == 0));

{
  person &&
    person.map((data, index) => (
      <div
        className={`${
          isCorrectCondition(index)
            ? "correct"
            : ""
        }`}
      >
        <div>{data.name}</div>
      </div>
    ));
}
```

Comment: It should start with with 8 and above

Comment: How about now? @Joseph

Comment: If value of index is like 8,9, 16,17, 24, 25.  In short multiples of 8 and 8 plus 1 and should start from 8 and above

Comment: Yeah, this should handle those cases

Comment: Why not @Shyam? If it weren't there, 0 and 1 would also result into `true` which is not what OP wanted!

Comment: yeah correct . looks like i need to brush up my math skills :-D

Comment: I've tested it @Joseph. Can you please mention the input for which you think this would be incorrect!?

Comment: yeah it seems to work fine . https://jsbin.com/keyawufibo/edit?js,console